# Sql query for Distinct names for max salary

Tags: sql

```
1 shreya cpn 10000
2 shreya cpna 100000
3 shreya cpnaa 20000
4 preeti buld 30000
5 preeti bulda 20000
6 preeti buldan 25000
1 sushil mal 30000
1 sushil male 10000
1 sushil maleg 15000
9 abc ada 15000
```

this is my table...
and this is my query `select * from stu where sal in (select MAX(sal)from stu group by name)`
and ans is-

```
2 shreya cpna 100000
4 preeti buld 30000
1 sushil mal 30000
1 sushil maleg 15000
9 abc ada 15000
10 sss sfsfs 12000
```

its displaying 2 sushil...where i want only distinct names for that...
plzz give me suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only `name` and `salary` columns in you output you can simply try this code:

```
select name, MAX(sal) from stu group by name
```

You can use columns in selection that you are grouping on as well as other columns with aggregated function.

In case you need all the other columns you will have to use `join`.

```
select s1.* 
from stu s1
join (select name, MAX(sal) as sal from stu group by name) as s2
on s1.name = s2.name and s1.sal = s2.sal
```

Comment: @Suyog, consider [accepting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) the answer if it helped.